# Clean Install - Dual boot Windows/Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I'm going to install Windows (as default boot - for a daily use/games) on a new computer, with a new SSD.

I'd like to add a dual boot for Ubuntu (for more technical uses - Development).

What do you suggest ?

First install Windows, then add Ubuntu ?
Is 20Go enough for Ubuntu ?
Any tips ?

Thanks !

Comment: Start with Windows

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: @bastien Are you asking us to recommend some software, such as a boot loader? If not, this question is off-topic.

Comment: @Mawg then where should I ask my question ? It's not hardware, it's not software, it's not about code..?

Comment: could be on-topic on superuser but probably a duplicate.

Comment: Yes. And Yes. You are doubly correct there (+1). And the answer is almost certainly the `Grub` bootloader (which has copious documentation)

Comment: While it depends on what you want to do with it, 20gB should be enough for Linux. You are only likely to need more for movies & the like, which you don't need in your VM, as you can make a shared directory & red them directly from your Windows drive. If you dual boot, Linux can certainly read NTFS, Google to find out about writing, and about extFS or whatever the new Windows file system is called. IIRC, there are also Windows programs to access Linux partitions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably start with Windows, because it's more finicky about how it boots/runs.  And then add ubuntu in a separate partition.  But really, what I do is run ubuntu in a virtual machine, that's so much better than mucking about with boot partitions..

Comment: I can't find anything to disagree with there (+1). Dual booting is so annoying when after you reboot you find that all documents are closed (plus the reboot time). Use a VM (VirtualBox is probably the best free one), and don't forget a shared directory (tree) to transfer files between Windows & Linux, plus sharing the clipboard.

Comment: This might almost be a viable alternative to both dual boot and a VM - the [Windows Linux Subsystem](https://cepa.io/2018/02/10/linuxizing-your-windows-pc-part1/) can run X, which means Linux programs with GUIs, running straight from DOS.

Comment: I haven't tried that Linux Subsystem Mawg, so can't speak to it.  But I do run docker containers on Windows without trouble, docker toolbox in win7 even

Comment: So, to be clear, you are running a Docker Linux (which is "like a mini-VM") on Windows? Maybe you could post more info as an answer? I am sure that it would help others? With over 100k containers at https://hub.docker.com/ there should be something for everyone